# PHP , SQL Show all whiskie dates and names as per name=:id an

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to show all the whiskies from my database with the dates alongside it , from the URL. I have several whiskies iwth the same names and want to show the price changes over the years. My current code is as below , but at the moment it is just showing one date , name and price. I am happy to show the one name at the top, but I would like to show all the prices and dates. [test_db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64V0I.png)

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
$sql = "SELECT date , name , price  FROM test_db WHERE name = :id ORDER BY name ASC";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute( [ 'id' => $_GET['id'] ] );
$row = $stmt->fetch();
echo "<div class='details'>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['name'];
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo $row ['date'];
    echo"<br><br>";
    echo " £";
    echo floor ($row ['price']);
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Just iterate through the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have several result you should use a loop   eg:

```
while( $row = $stmt->fetch() ) {
    echo "<div class='details'>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo $row['name'];
        echo "<br><br>";
        echo $row ['date'];
        echo"<br><br>";
        echo " £";
        echo floor ($row ['price']);
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<br>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```